# How can I make sure only one thread performs IO from a file?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, io, locking

Here's my use case (using C++): I have a multithreaded environment performing operations on data structures written on disk. There are M files. The workflow is:

1. Thread reads from file into a data structure
2. Operations on the data structure are performed
3. The data structure is inserted in cache
4. Last recently used element is written on file

Cache insertions and deletions are thread-safe already. However, I have no idea how to parallelize writes and reads, ie if Thread 1 is reading from File 1, then Thread 2 can read from File 2. Of course Thread 2 should not read from File 1. If I simply insert a mutex, the whole section is locked and only one thread can read at the same time. What is the most efficient way to make sure only one thread reads from one file, but multiple files are read at the same time?

edit: code is something like this

```
for element in elements
    file = element.txt
    data = file.read()
    cache.insert(data)
```

Comment: Having one mutex per file ?

Comment: sure, but how do I implement this? I cannot find any kind of examples or pseudocode

Comment: If nobody is writing, I think *files* can have multiple readers unless some platform limitations I've never heard of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put file name in an std::map as a key. Then add mutex pointer as a value. Then whenever a thread has a file name to work on, it locks using the mutex and a lock guard.

```
{
  lock_guard<mutex> lg (*mapping[filename] );
  compute(filename);
}
```

As OS has its own file cache, it would be good to use read-lock to let multiple threads read a file concurrently and still lock against writing by a unique lock.